# Reduce processing time of saveXML

Tags: php, domdocument

I use PHP and there are tow APPs.

One APP, named APP-1, handles over 800,000 rows of Oracle DB to XML document.

Another APP, named APP-2, that takes XML from APP-1 as http response and show the data as Web page.

Maximum data, APP-2 can request for APP-1 is 100,000 rows.

If APP-2 wants to get whole 800,000 rows APP-2 has to make request APP-1 for 8 times.

Now I run APP-2 and APP-1.

And APP-1 finished in 300 sec for processing all rows.

Now I want know how to reduce processing time.

APP-1 generates XML with saveXML. It takes 25 sec in average, 180 sec in total. It is nearly a half of whole processing time.

On the other hand APP-2 is much faster than APP-1.

APP-2 parses XML with simplexml_load_string and changes into HTML. It takes 5sec in average 35 sec in total.

I think 100,000 rows doesn’t key factor for processing time because simplexml_load_string is much faster than saveXML..

Is there any good solution to reduce processing time for the part saveXML does?

Comment: Any chance you can switch to other data format, e.g. JSON or even custom-made ones? The thought is to do it as "plain" as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, a DOM document will need relatively much memory, as the whole document tree must be held in memory. DOM is good for parsing and manipulating existing xml content. If you just need to output XML I would **not** suggest to use a document for it. Just plain string output would fit most. Like this:

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>';
echo '<data>';
while($row = $result->fetchRecord()) {
    echo '<row>
            <foo><![CDATA[' . $ow['foo'] . ']]></foo>
            <bar><![CDATA[' . $row['bar'] . ']]></bar>
          </row>';
}
echo '</data>';
```

You could increase that performance using output buffering:

```
ob_start(4096); // start buffering of output using a 4096 bytes sized buffer

echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>';
echo '<data>';
while($row = $result->fetchRecord()) {
    echo '<row>
            <foo><![CDATA[' . $ow['foo'] . ']]></foo>
            <bar><![CDATA[' . $row['bar'] . ']]></bar>
          </row>';
}
echo '</data>';

ob_end_flush();
```

Note if your content from database might containt content like `]]>` (what would close the CDATA sections, it must be escaped before using. This is especially the case if you have binary data.

Comment: Actually I have 4GB physical memory. And 1.7GB was free while APP-1 processing. I think 1.7GB is enough.

Comment: It's not about the *enough*. Its about the time it takes to reserve that memory (node by node) and handle DOM operations. It's pure overhead to use DOM. Try my example and you'll see

Comment: `printf` may not be suitable for string "sanitizing", e.g. `printf("<element>%s</element>","<malformed>")` will not output `<element>&lt;malformed&gt;</element>`, but just `<element><malformed></element>`. That's the advantage of XML library.

Comment: Ok I'll try it see on monday.

Comment: @Passerby Note that is just true under the assumption that there is sensitive data in the database. This is off topic for my simple example. But I have replaced the `printf()` by `echo` as `printf()` is bad for performance (what is the topic of the question)

Comment: @hek2mgl It's not about security; it's about XML validity. `<element><malformed></element>` is not valid XML, and may cause error on the other end.

Comment: @Passerby Yes, I know what you mean. Maybe `sensitive` was the wrong word. Note that I'm not a native speaker. Beside from malformed content, which has to be sanitized of course, wouldn't you agree with the answer?

Comment: @hek2mgl Me neither :) It's just that, depending on the nature of the content, there may be high chances that `<`, `>`, `"`, etc. "malformed" characters need to appear in XML attribute or node value. XML builder is responsible for "encoding" these characters to proper form. Directly `echo` may causes problem; at least `htmlentities`/`htmlspecialchars` is needed. But of course, that's still faster than DOM.

Comment: @Passerby If content can contain special chars, I would recomment using `CDATA` sections. Check my update

Comment: I honestly don't see what the fuss is about. DOMDocument uses a horrendous amount of memory in total (not due to bad optimization, by the way - just the amount of data that is actually vital), and if you've got all the data...Why can't you write your script without using `DOMDocument`? DOM only comes in handy to parse, or if you're injecting a fragment in a document. For the rest, there's output buffering.

Comment: (Also, don't be fooled, output buffering yields a large use of RAM... about 10x less, though)

Comment: @hek2mgl: I'm on your side on this one, dude. Echoing + adding facts.

Comment: (As for malformed XML, one can easily write their script to intelligently track the order of opened tags... using a stack. Takes under 20 bytes per opened tag. So the "malformed XML tag" part can be trivially avoided)

Comment: Ah ok.. :) Note that I've tested this once with a site where xml output took seconds, after that it took just 0.1 ... seconds :)

Comment: @SébastienRenauld Thanks for substantiating the answer! :)

Comment: I tried hek2mgl’s way. APP-1 finished in 100 sec for processing all rows. Generating XML incredibly reduce processing time, it took 0.5 msec in average, 0.05 msec in total.Thank you. How do you know DOM takes so much overhead?

Comment: It's because just outputting the string takes zero overhead. But DOM requires to have a complex construct with pointers in memory to represent the xml-tree. But the most important thing would be that it is necessary to have **the whole large document** in memory at once.